# Use an image file link to display a random banner

Tags: php, mysql, url-rewriting, http-headers, banner

Not sure if this is even appropriate here, but I'm trying to work out how a banner rotator website is using standard html image code, to return a random banner?

```
<a target=_blank href=http://intellibanners.com/click.php?cid=campaign1>
    <img border=0 src=http://intellibanners.com/campaign1.jpg>
</a>
```

In the example above, that html will display a random image from that campaign.

This started as a bit of a whim to see if I could set up something similar to work with different image sizes, but now it's driving me nuts... trying to figure out how to go from a image url to a database call to send back a different image!?

No lucky searching for ideas or examples, probably because I don't know what sort of processes or functions I should actually be looking for?

I'm thinking there must be some sort of url rewrite for all image calls, that redirects to a handler script...

That script makes the database call, grabs a random image from the nominated campaign, updates stats etc...

And possibly a php header response returns the corresponding image file?

But most of that is new to me and I'm not sure where/how to search for guidance or examples to get me started.

If anyone has any ideas on this, or even the kind of phrasing/functions I need that might help me get there in my own searching, it would be much appreciated!

(I've also installed and tested about 12 different rotator scripts hoping to find one that works the same, but no luck there either).

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: See you my answer. Hope this helps...

Comment: If you don't want rename your banner images you can take the original names, my script will work in any way...

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, but the standard banner rotator isn't what I was after. I was looking to use a database of banner/link combos that are rotated through the exact same snippet of code on multiple 3rd party websites. The site I mentioned is doing it, but I don't understand how... I can see how the banner url might rewrite/redirect to a page that retrieves a random banner from that url, but I'm curious how the correct image is sent to the browser... and if the user clicks, how the handler script (click.php) knows which banner was shown so it can redirect to the correct url.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a php script that assumes to exist the wanted folders in the root of your website. Then you can invoke it in a simple way in any location of your website. Here is my script:

`rotate.php`

```
<?php
  ##########################################################
  # Simple Script Random Images Rotator • 1.4 • 04.01.2020 #
  # Alessandro Marinuzzi [alecos] • https://www.alecos.it/ #
  ##########################################################
  function rotate($folder) {
    if ((file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$folder")) && (is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$folder"))) {
      $list = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$folder");
      $fileList = array();
      $img = '';
      foreach ($list as $file) {
        if ((file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . "/$folder/$file")) && (is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . "/$folder/$file"))) {
          $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
          if ($ext == 'gif' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'png') {
            $fileList[] = $file;
          }
        }
      }
      if (count($fileList) > 0) {
        $imageNumber = time() % count($fileList);
        $img = $folder . '/' . $fileList[$imageNumber];
      }
      return $img;
    } else {
      mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/$folder", 0755, true);
    }
  }
?>
```

Now you can create a `index.php` file where you want and put this line:

`<?php include("your_path/rotate.php"); ?>`

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://intellibanners.com/click.php?cid=campaign1">
    <img border="0" src="/<?php echo rotate('campaign1'); ?>">
</a>
```

other like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://intellibanners.com/click.php?cid=campaign2">
    <img border="0" src="/<?php echo rotate('campaign2'); ?>">
</a>
```

and so that...

You have only to create the wished folders in the root called `campaign1`, `campaign2`...etc...

then in each folder put the banner images of the current campaign...

for example: in the folder `campaign1` put image like `001.png`, `002,png`, `003.png`, `004.jpg`, `005.jpg`... (where these filenames match your campaign banners).

for example: in the folder `campaign2` put image like `001.png`, `002,png`, `003.png`, `004.jpg`, `005.jpg`, `006.gif`, `007.png`, `008.jpg`... (where these filenames match your campaign banners).

Please note that if you don't want rename your banner images you can take the original names, my script will work in any way.

My script will turn all in wished output like this:

`campaign1`:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://intellibanners.com/click.php?cid=campaign1">
    <img border="0" src="/campaign1/002.jpg">
</a>

<a target="_blank" href="http://intellibanners.com/click.php?cid=campaign1">
    <img border="0" src="/campaign1/007.jpg">
</a>
```

`campaign2`:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://intellibanners.com/click.php?cid=campaign2">
    <img border="0" src="/campaign2/004.png">
</a>

<a target="_blank" href="http://intellibanners.com/click.php?cid=campaign2">
    <img border="0" src="/campaign2/005.gif">
</a>
```

See you and test all into your localhost website... for me works fine on PHP 7.4.5 and Apache 2.4.43.

The script will do the rest!

Hope this helps you!